# Custom search template is showing 404 when adding query string

Tags: theme-development, search, page-template

I've created a custom theme and a page template `page-search.php`, because the original search will search under the homepage url.

The page works just fine without query string but when I add `/?s=1` at the end of the URL I get a 404, why is that?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a 404 or is it "no posts found" or similar? Those are two separate things. If you use `?s=1` in the URL then WordPress interprets that as a search query, searches for posts containing "1", then tries to load search.php from the theme, or index.php if it doesn't exist.

Comment: It's because you change the main query by adding `s`, so unless your custom search page also matches the search it will find nothing. A page and a page template aren't how you should customize the URL of your search

Comment: @TomJNowell How would you customize the search URL? I don't mind using search.php but it's sending me to the homepage

Comment: @JacobPeattie It's a 404 not found

Comment: @odedta did you implement your custom homepage in `index.php`? Are you aware of `home.php` and `frontpage.php`?

Comment: I have `index.php` for most pages, `front-page.php` for homepage. Also, I will get a 404 even if I try `?test=test`